# Apply DFT matrix along each axis of 3D array in NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy

I can first obtain the DFT matrix of a given size, say `n` by

```
import numpy as np
n = 64
D = np.fft.fft(np.eye(n))
```

The FFT is of course just a quick algorithm for applying `D` to a vector:

```
x = np.random.randn(n)
ft1 = np.dot(D,x)
print( np.abs(ft1 - fft.fft(x)).max() )
# prints near double precision roundoff
```

The 2D FFT can be obtained by applying `D` to both the rows and columns of a matrix:

```
x = np.random.randn(n,n)
ft2 = np.dot(x, D.T) # Apply D to rows.
ft2 = np.dot(D, ft2) # Apply D to cols.
print( np.abs(ft2 - fft.fft2(x)).max() )
# near machine round off again
```

**How do I compute this analogously for the 3 dimensional Discrete Fourier Transform?**

I.e.,

```
x = np.random.randn(n,n,n)
ft3 = # dot operations using D and x
print( np.abs(ft3 - fft.fftn(x)).max() )
# prints near zero
```

Essentially, I think I need to apply `D` to each column vector in the volume, then each row vector in the volume, and finally each "depth vector". But I'm not sure how to do this using `dot`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `einsum` expression to perform the transformation on each index:

```
x = np.random.randn(n, n, n)
ft3 = np.einsum('ijk,im->mjk', x, D)
ft3 = np.einsum('ijk,jm->imk', ft3, D)
ft3 = np.einsum('ijk,km->ijm', ft3, D)
print(np.abs(ft3 - np.fft.fftn(x)).max())
1.25571216554e-12
```

This can also be written as a single NumPy step:

```
ft3 = np.einsum('ijk,im,jn,kl->mnl', ft3, D, D, D, optimize=True)
```

Without the optimize argument (available in NumPy 1.12+) it will be very slow however. You can also do each of the steps using `dot`, but it requires a bit of reshaping and transposing. In NumPy 1.14+ the `einsum` function will automatically detect the BLAS operations and do this for you.

Comment: Wow, this `optimize` switch is a game changer. Without it the one-liner is all but unusable. Btw. you can save a whopping 5 characters by specifying `'ikm,ij,kl,mn'`.