# Applying DCT matrix along each axis not giving the desired result

Tags: python, numpy, fft, dct

Using the following code, I would expect to get `linalg.norm(y-z)` equals zero. I follow the idea of [Apply DFT matrix along each axis of 3D array in NumPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48290758/apply-dft-matrix-along-each-axis-of-3d-array-in-numpy) since FFT and DCT are both separable, unitary linear transforms. But somehow this isn't the case.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.fftpack import dct 

x = np.random.rand(5,5)

D = dct(np.eye(5), norm='ortho')
y = np.dot(D,np.dot(x, D.T))
z = dct(dct(x, axis = 0 , norm = 'ortho'), axis = 1 , norm = 'ortho')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Pick* **one** *of the following solutions.*

1. Redefine `D` by specifying `axis=0`:

   ```
   D = dct(np.eye(n), axis=0, norm="ortho")
   ```
2. Redefine `D` by specifying `.T` and using the default `axis=-1` (doesn't really generalize to higher dimensions...):

   ```
   D = dct(np.eye(n), norm="ortho").T
   ```
3. Use `D.T @ x` to represent a DCT along `axis=0` of `x`:

   ```
   y = D.T @ x @ D
   ```

The order doesn't matter in the case of DFT since the matrix is symmetric (`D == D.T`) *in addition* to being unitary (`D.conj().T @ D == I`). But the DCT matrix is not symmetric, so you have to be careful of what order you use.

Consider the definition for DCT-II:

[image]

When you construct the operator `D` to imply that `D @ x` takes the DCT-II along the rows (`axis=0`), then `D` must be defined so that the covariance and contravariance of the transformation are properly handled.

---

Full example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.fftpack import dct 

n = 5
x = np.random.rand(n, n)

D = dct(np.eye(n), axis=0, norm="ortho")
y = D @ x @ D.T

z = x
z = dct(z, axis=0, norm="ortho")
z = dct(z, axis=1, norm="ortho")
```

```
>>> np.linalg.norm(z - y)
6.20161216470283e-16
```